# Is this a g.c.d. domain? Then why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ for  $d \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then, is the domain $R$ a g.c.d. domain?

(Intuitively it looks like true, but couldn't figure out the reason of that. )

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Note that in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, you have $6 = 2\cdot 3 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: Then... g.c.d. of the 4($2,3, 1 + \sqrt -5$ etc) elements would be $1$ when calculating the norm. Hence your domain suggested to me would be g.c.d. domain. Similarly $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is g.c.d. domain. Is my guess right?

Comment: What is a gcd domain? I know what a Euclidean domain,  a UFD and a PID are.

Comment: Here is the expaination in wikipedia .https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain

Comment: So what is the smallest principal ideal containing $6$?

Comment: Is it $<6>$? Since $<a>$ is the smallest ideal containing the $a$.

Comment: But shouldn't the smallest ideal be generated by the gcd you claimed?

Comment: No, I'm wrong. I should have said the smallest ideal containing $2$, $3$, $1\pm\sqrt{-5}$. But, I have not thought about this enough. With just a pair, we get $\langle 1\rangle$. Presumably violating UFD or PID isn't enough to violate gcd domain. We need an algebraist.

Comment: Mr @Ted Shifrin,  I found the similar answer in stack overflow. It seems we found the answer.  Here is the link. :) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11105/an-example-of-two-elements-without-a-greatest-common-divisor

Comment: Ah, yup, just pairs. Better to do thorough searches before making us look stupid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already solved before.

The conclusion is  the $R$ is not g.c.d. domain When we consider general case without the special cases like when the $R$ is UFD.(e.g. gaussian  integer ring $Z[i]$)

Hence For the $R$, we can't say any two elements have a g.c.d.

Here is the reason.

the link
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11105/an-example-of-two-elements-without-a-greatest-common-divisor